# Steady state Solution of ODEs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please find a Steady state Solution of this ODE.

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+5y = \frac{2}{3}\pi^2 +\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{4}{n^2}(-1)^{n+1} cos(nx)$

Firstly, the solution of Homogeneous ODE $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+5y = 0$ is $y=C_1e^{(-1+2i)x}+C_2e^{(-1-2i)x}$  where $C_1, C_2$ are constants.
And... For particular solutions. How should i do ?

Comment: It's have been a long time since your last upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[msm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/350875/msm) has already provide the steady state solution. Regarding the particular solution, one should consider the following form: 
$$ y_p(x) = C + \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{4}{n^2} (-1)^{n+1} \bigg[ A_n \cos(nx) + B_n \sin(nx) \bigg]$$
where $C, A_n, B_n$ are constants. Replacing $g(x)$ in the left hand side you easily find that $$C = \frac{2}{15} \pi^2.$$ 
Replacing $y_p(x)$ in the left hand side gives the following set of equations for any given $n$:
$$ \begin{align} (5-n^2) A_n + 2n B_n &= 1 \\ -2n A_n + (5-n^2) B_n &= 0 \end{align} $$
which gives you,
$$ A_n = \frac{5-n^2}{n^4-6n^2+25}, \qquad B_n=\frac{2n}{n^4-6n^2+25}.$$

Comment: What is the difference between The steady state solution and Just solution?